# find value in array of objects nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have array of objects and I can not receive value of one property of it.
Console.log of row.parent_id is undefined
Please explaine why If every object has parent_id property

```
 [{ _id: 5c94b9f0e5a1cf63ccb29bd1,
   parent_id: 0,
   title: 'Home',
   icon: 'fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-home',
   route: '/home',
   badge: [] },
 { _id: 5c94b9f0e5a1cf63ccb29bd2,
   parent_id: 0,
   title: 'Blog',
   icon: 'fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-blogger',
   route: '/views/blog',
   badge:
    { label: 'hot',
      class: 'badge pull-right inbox-badge bg-color-yellow' } }]

   docs.forEach (function (row,key) {
           console.log('par',row.parent_id)
          if(row.parent_id === 0 ){
              result.push(row)
          }
      })
      console.log('res',result)
```

I dont understand why but if I add to variable this objects manualy it works but didnt works if I get it from mongo db, but objects are identical

Comment: Your code works fine for me

Comment: can you share full code

Comment: Isn’t there a comma missing between the two objects in the array?

Comment: There look to be some issues in the JSON. Comma between the two objects. And the badge property is inconsistent... THoguh that doesn't wont make a difference here

Comment: I dont understand why but if I add to variable this objects manualy it works but didnt works if I get it from mongo db, but objects are identical

Answer (score 0):

First off all, you have some errors in code, missing quotation marks and comma between two objects. If you want to check, if every object has parent_id property, use filter fn.

```
const docs = [{ _id: "5c94b9f0e5a1cf63ccb29bd1",
   parent_id: 0,
   title: 'Home',
   icon: 'fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-home',
   route: '/home',
   badge: [] },
 { _id: "5c94b9f0e5a1cf63ccb29bd2",
   parent_id: 0,
   title: 'Blog',
   icon: 'fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-blogger',
   route: '/views/blog',
   badge:
    { label: 'hot',
      class: 'badge pull-right inbox-badge bg-color-yellow' } }]

console.log(docs.filter(item => item.parent_id !== 'undefined'))
```

Be carefull, when comparing with 0, != always returns false, !== 'undefined' checks, if there is value. If in your case 0 is not correct value, just compare with 0.

Comment: I dont understand why but if I add to variable this objects manualy it works but didnt works if I get it from mongo db, but objects are identical

Answer (score 0):

Did you check whether your for loop execution comes inside the block?
The object doesn’t look like an array. 
An array elements must be separated with `,`. 
Looking at the logic it looks like you want to filter out all elements whose `parent_id` is not zero. That can be done like

`reult = docs.filter(element => element.parent_id === ‘0’)`

Comment: I dont understand why but if I add to variable this objects manualy it works but didnt works if I get it from mongo db, but objects are identical